# C3.js Add additional informations to tick

Tags: javascript, angularjs, c3.js

i have format for tick:

```
               tick: {
                    fit: true,
                    multiline: false,
                    outer: false,
                    format: function (x) {
                        var value = this.api.categories()[x];
                        if(value.length > 5)
                            return value.substring(0,5)+"...";
                        else
                            return value;
                    }
                },
```

`value` - unique attribute. But now - i should cut it by 5 symbol.

and i have click on tick:

```
_.each(this.chart.element.querySelectorAll('svg g.c3-axis-x .tick text tspan'), (el) => {
            el.onclick = (e) => this.someFunction(e)
        })
```

in someFunction() - i want to get unique attribute to get data for current tick.

Earliest i got this attribute like `angular.element(e.target).text()` but it can contain сropped attribute. How i can get current index? or something else to get full text

Answer (score 0):

Getting data/indices out of elements in a c3 chart is best done via d3, as that's what c3 is using to build them in the first place. Whether using angular breaks this capability I don't know though, as I don't use it

What would be worth trying, is if you look at your previous q ([C3 js : large axis label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45608611/c3-js-large-axis-label)) then changing just part of my answer to it gives click capability in the onrendered function:

```
onrendered: function () {
    var self = this;

    d3.select(this.config.bindto)
        .selectAll(".c3-axis-x .tick text")
        .on ("click", function(d) {
           console.log ("data val", d, "gives us ", self.api.categories()[d])
            // then do what you want
        })
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/05hsk6yh/3/